# Laravel Zizaco Role and Permission Error BadMethod Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-views

> 1/4 BadMethodCallException in Repository.php line 352: This cache
>   store does not support tagging.

this the error 1 when i use the role blade syntax on my view blade template.

Actually the erroe started when i use the tinker cli i got got the badMethodcall error when i tried to save with the

> save()

next

> 1/2 ErrorException in Repository.php line 352: This cache store does
>   not support tagging. (View:
>   C:\Users\Ilamini\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\dash\resources\views\partials\topnav.blade.php)

next error

> 3/4 ErrorException in Repository.php line 352: This cache store does
>   not support tagging. (View:
>   C:\Users\Ilamini\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\dash\resources\views\partials\topnav.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\Users\Ilamini\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\dash\resources\views\partials\topnav.blade.php)

Final Error

> 4/4 ErrorException in Repository.php line 352: This cache store does
>   not support tagging. (View:
>   C:\Users\Ilamini\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\dash\resources\views\partials\topnav.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\Users\Ilamini\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\dash\resources\views\partials\topnav.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\Users\Ilamini\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\dash\resources\views\partials\topnav.blade.php)

Please do any one know how to correct this.

Comment: Which version of Entrust are you using?

Comment: `"zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev",`